# Column Sorting Removed Filters in Find Contribution

Tags: civicontribute

We just upgraded to 5.19.1, but not sure when this started. When we go to Find Contributions, put some criteria in, get results, and then click on one of the column headers to sort the results, it completely removes any of the Search Criteria.

I see it happens on the 5.19.0 demo site as well.  Is this a known bug?

Comment: No idea (yet) but i have flagged this on the maintenance channel in chat.civicrm.org

Comment: someone in that channel just said: suspect its the same issue as https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1374 which EIleen put up this PR https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/15781 which has been merged into 5.20, Her feeling at the time was that it wouldn't get backported back to 5.19

Comment: if you can confirm is same issue then i will paste above as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like one of the amazing maintenance team have already provided a patch for this so it should be in the next release

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/15896

Don't you just love the CiviCRM Community - this is all being done by volunteers - you can support the community in a number of ways via https://civicrm.org/support-us (not suggesting you aren't currently supporting it)

Comment: Confirming it went in tonight’s security release;

Comment: Thank you! Totally agree, the team/community is amazing. Huge to get a quick response like this. And yes, we are supporters and we also spread the word to others orgs to support as well!